# RTK useLazyQuery trigger onClick data not refreshed

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm a newbie on RTK queries and I currently have this problem

What i'm trying to do here is after `trigger()`, i need to access result in the `onClickHandler` to process, but when i `console.log` the `result`, i keep getting the initObject of

```
    {
      currentData: undefined
      data: undefined
      isError: false
      isFetching: false
      isLoading: false
      isSuccess: false
      isUninitialized: true
      status: "uninitialized"
    }
```

Here is a small snippet of the code

```
const ComponentA = (props) => {
   const [trigger, result] = useLazyQuery(); 

    const onClickHandler = () => {
       trigger();
       console.log(result);
    };

    return (
      <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Button</button>
    )

}
```

My question is what do i need to get the data that is coming back from the query?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to unwrap it if you are using Redux Toolkit.

Something like this should work:

```
const ComponentA = (props) => {
const [trigger] = useLazyQuery(); 

const onClickHandler = async () => {
   const result = await trigger().unwrap();
   console.log(result);
};

return (
  <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Button</button>
)
```

}

https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#unwrapping-result-actions